# how to find a code of a java class

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using in my java servlet the method:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I wanna to know how can I see the source code behind this interface.

Comment: Question 1: What OS are you running on? Question 2: Are you using Eclipse? (makes it much easier to find that stuff:) ). This is practically basic stuff you learn in most coding books tho.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a link to the source code of many Java built in libraries

[Reference for the servlet request class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.4/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.java)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of HttpServletRequest is the one provided by your servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, ...). So, if your container is opensource, print the class of the request:

```
System.out.prinln(request.getClass());
```

then find the sources of the servlet container and browse for the class that has been printed. The web page of the container, most of the time, says where the sources can be found.

That said, the contract of the method is well documented in the interface, and you shouldn't have to know how it's implemented to use the method. The documentation should be sufficient.